# ASP.NET C# REST WEB API - POST Multiple JSON values

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am struggling to find a solution to my problem: I have a really simple Web API in C# that GET, POST, PUT and DELETE employees nicely, but everything working with a simple JSON input:

```
{
   "FirstName": "Sam 10",
   "LastName": "Wicht 10",
   "Gender": "Male",
   "Salary": 140000
}
```

What I want to do is to POST a lot of employees, like:

```
"employees": [{
   "FirstName": "Sam 10",
   "LastName": "Wicht 10",
   "Gender": "Male",
   "Salary": 140000
}, {
   "FirstName": "Sam 11",
   "LastName": "Wicht 11",
   "Gender": "Male",
   "Salary": 99000
}]
```

And in my C# Code, I receive, for instance a `List<Employee>` containing every employee from JSon and then I loop a For Each ... updating each.

Performance-wise, is this something really bad? Thinking I can limit the List size and avoid running any code if `.Count()` is higher than X, can you guys please let me know how to retrieve this from the JSON input?

This is the class Employee I have:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Salary { get; set; }
}
```

Should I include a new Class that represents an `IEnumerable<Employee>` with all the parameters?

This is for learning and testing purposes, and I tried to retrieve `[FromBody] List<Employee> myVariableName; returns null;`

Comment: Your edit removing the bulk of the question's content made it incoherent and rendered the answer meaningless. Do not vandalize your questions. Edits are only intended to clarify and/or add additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting null because you have an enclosing `employee` object in your sample json. POST instead:

```
[{
   "FirstName": "Sam 10",
   "LastName": "Wicht 10",
   "Gender": "Male",
   "Salary": 140000
}, {
   "FirstName": "Sam 11",
   "LastName": "Wicht 11",
   "Gender": "Male",
   "Salary": 99000
}]
```

And that will match your controller definition of:

```
public ActionResult Post(List<Employee> employees)
```